# is there an blacklist list for Better Pop Up Blocker?

Tags: blocking, popups, blacklist

I have Better Pop Up Blocker, it is really annoying to keep adding sites to my whitelist.

I like to use the blacklist mode (to block pop-up only for bad sites as opposed to my banking sites), but making a good blacklist list takes time and it doesn't save it on all my computers (work, home, etc.).

I wonder if there are any already-made blacklists for Better Pop Up Blocker?

Answer (score 0):

My advice goes for an extension change for Adblock Plus.

It has several lists, updated on a regular basis and you really don't have to configure or change it more than once or twice.

[Chrome version](http://adblockplus.org/en/chrome)

[Firefox Version](http://adblockplus.org/en/firefox)

[Opera Version](http://adblockplus.org/en/opera)

Comment: I used to use that one, but it did NOT block some sites at all...

Comment: you probably had the wrong subscription for your location, or not enough subscriptions active so it would be effective. i have no complaints whatsoever about this software.